# Testcases for grails 1.3.7

Tags: grails, grails-orm, grails-plugin, grails-controller

I was wondering if there are any example application or plugins that have test cases written against them. 
I'm starting to write more test cases for the applications in grails 1.3.7 
I'm working and wanted to see how other people are writing their test for grails.

Thanks,

Comment: Checkout source of some of the grails plugins, many of them have tests

Comment: you can write your code in unitTest file and check out the cases...